# Cookie не дают работать, как их временно уволить?

Tags: html, cookie

Редактирую скрипт сайта - для проверки взаимодействия пользователей требуется в него войти с одного компьютера (разные браузеры, сам сайт на Denwer'е), но cookie не пускают сделать вторую учетную запись пользователя.

Что нужно временно убрать из `<head></head>` для корректной работы?
(хотя я не уверен, что именно в этом отрезке кода дело)

**Код:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?php echo fw::config('title'); ?></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo WEB; ?>style/<?php echo fw::config('style'); ?>/image/favicon.png"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo WEB; ?>style/<?php echo fw::config('style'); ?>/style.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo WEB; ?>style/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var WEB = '<?php echo WEB; ?>';
   var CONST_WEB = '<?php echo WEB; ?>';
   var CONST_ORDER = '<?php echo fw::route(0); ?>';
   var LANG_LOADING = '<?php echo lang('loading'); ?>';
   <?php foreach(fw::$vars as $key=>$value): ?>
   var <?php echo $key; ?> = <?php echo json_encode($value); ?>;
   <?php endforeach; ?>   
  </script>
  <?php foreach(fw::$js as $file): ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   <?php foreach(fw::$scripts as $script): ?>
   <?php echo $script; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  </script>  
  
  <?php if(fw::config('style') == 'administration'): ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEB; ?>js/scrollbar/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo WEB; ?>js/scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo WEB; ?>js/scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css"/>  

  <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    "use strict";
    $('#sidebar').perfectScrollbar();
   });       
  </script>
  <?php endif; ?>
  
  <?php echo fw::config('head'); ?>
 </head>
 
 <body>

  <?php require_once CWEB.'style/'.fw::config('style').'/template.html'; ?>
    
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: в Firefox/Chome браузере есть приватный режим которым можно воспользоваться что бы проверить работу под несколькими пользователями, т.е. запускаем браузер в обычном режиме, и потом открываем второй экземпляр. в *Firefox* это называется *Приватное окно*, в *Chrome* - *Новое окно в режиме Инкогнито*. так же можно попробовать portable версии

Comment: coockie могут передаваться через Set-Cookie header.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте очистить cookie с помощью js.

[похожий запрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595228/how-can-i-delete-all-cookies-with-javascript)

```
function clearListCookies(){
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){   
        var spcook =  cookies[i].split("=");
        document.cookie = spcook[0] + "=;expires=Thu, 21 Sep 1979 00:00:01 UTC;";                                
    }
}
```